# Match values within a range from uneven data frames

Tags: r

Thank you for your help in advance.

I have two data frames DataBase and Hits

```
DataBase=
X  Y    OTDB
0   0    OTDB001
2  14   OTDB002
0   0.5  OTDB003 

Hits=
X   Y       Signal
0    0       100
2.1 14.3   20
7    15       90

Results=
X   Y    Signal  OTDB
0    0    100      OTDB001
0    0    100      OTDB003
2.1 14.3 20      OTDB002
7     15   90       NA
```

For every X, Y in Hits I want to search the database to see if there is a corresponding value within a threshold of X+/- 0.1 and Y+/- 0.5. If there is a value(s) that matches within the threshold I want to add the OTDB number or "NA" to a new column in a Results data frame. It is likely multiple dataBase entries will match an X,Y from the hits.

For perfect matches of X,Y between Database and Hits I used

```
Results=merge(DataBase, Hits, by=c("X", "Y"), all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

However I'm having trouble setting the tolerance in searching. Thank you again for any advice!